# ASP controls losing state when hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a web page with a div:

```
<div runat="server" id="divNewCapture" style="padding-top: 30px; padding-bottom: 30px; padding-left: 20px">
...
</div>
```

Within this div I have an textbox that I use with a JQuery datepicker:

```
<input id="txtHtmlDateMarried" class="textEntry" style="width: 295px" />

$('#txtHtmlDateMarried').datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonImage: "Images/Calendar.png",
    dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
});
```

Server-side on Page_Load I hide the div:

```
divNewCapture.Visible = false;
```

When I show this div again at a later stage, the datepicker for the textbox is lost. It shows initially if I don't hide the div. (I want to fix this without any server-side code)

Comment: Is your javascript wrapped in jQuery ready? http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Please define what does "show this div again at a later stage" mean.

Comment: @Andrei: It makes sense when you say that setting `Visible` to false server side removes the control from the page. It is shown server side again simply by setting `Visible` to true on an `on_click` event. Making use of styles to hide the control does make much more sense, but I need a very quick (30min) html only solution to *temporarily fix an urgent issue without needing code-reviews etc., and fix the code later etc. What I did seems a bit ridiculous. I have javascript checking the existence every second, then applying the datepickers. Will fix the code probably after the weekend.

Comment: @Carel, I think you solution might work well, but that seems really like a workaround. So right, the best way is to get rid of this server-side code and manage this div on client side. Even remove "runat" attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `divNewCapture` is a server-side control, setting its `Visible` to false effectively removes the control from the page. I.e. when `Visible` is false, control is not rendered. Therefore datepicker does not see it when you initialize it.

If you want to hide control but make sure it is still on the page and is available for javascript calls, then operate with style. To hide:

```
btnSaveLineItems.Style["display"] = "none";
```

to show:

```
btnSaveLineItems.Style.Remove("display");
//or
btnSaveLineItems.Style["display"] = "block";
```

However perhaps better style would be to manage control's visibility on the client side completely.

Comment: While this is true, the op said he shows the div and the datepicker is still not shown. This does not address that problem.

Comment: @Esko, hmmm, you are probably right. However I can imagine scenario when my answer does address the problem (e.g with UpdatePanel on the page). I better ask OP about his specifics